# Trouble with Sequelize findOne() and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and was trying to run a basic query to find the first instance of model in my database. My model `user.js`:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('Northwind', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1433,
    dialect: 'mssql'
});

var User = sequelize.define('Employees', {
    Name: Sequelize.STRING,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false
});

module.exports = User;
```

And the the file, `api.js`, in my `Express.js` application where the code is called:

```
router.route('/posts')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        var user;

        User.find({
            where: {
                Name: 'matt'
            }            
        }).then(function (user) {
        console.log('found');
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
    res.send({
        message: 'Test string'
    });
});
```

I used the value "Matt" for I know it is in the table `Employees`. However, upon executing, I receive errors about which seem to indicate that Sequelize is trying to `SELECT` from columns I know do not exist in the `Employees` table like  `[id]`, `[createdAt]`, `[updatedAt]`. I believe it has to do with the `findOne()` command having a `(default)` execution, but I am not sure how to config.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs `attributes:['NameOfColumn1','NameOfColumn2', etc.]`

For example, in my case:

```
User.find({
      attributes: ['Name'],
      where: {
         Name: 'matt'
     }            
})
```

will only consider the column `Name` in the query. Woot. Also, unless `timestamps: false` is present in your model definition, your model will contain those values and may throw errors when querying if your table is not synced accordingly. For example, in my `User.js` model:

```
var User = sequelize.define('Users', {
    Username: Sequelize.STRING,
    Password: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    timestamps: false
});
```

Sorry for not finding this before asking :-/ Hope this information proves helpful to other Sequelize n00bs like me.